# databricks init script UI is empty

Tags: user-interface, databricks, azure-databricks, init

In the databricks cluster configuration UI, I am trying to add an init script. I have stored the script in the DBFS, however the init script UI has no drop down or obvious way to select this file. What am I missing? I have followed the instructions here:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/init-scripts#:~:text=Configure%20a%20cluster-scoped%20init%20script%20using%20the%20UI.,The%20path%20must%20...%205%20Click%20Add.%20](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/init-scripts#:%7E:text=Configure%20a%20cluster-scoped%20init%20script%20using%20the%20UI.,The%20path%20must%20...%205%20Click%20Add.%20)

Every tutorial that I find shows a UI that includes a destination, path, and add button. My UI shows none of that.

Answer (score 2):

init scripts must be added while the cluster is in edit mode.  The cluster must be terminated to be able to edit settings.  Once in edit mode, the init script UI is active.

Answer (score 0):

There is no selector in the Cluster UI - it's just a normal input field where you need to type or paste the path to the init script.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same question. It seems that you need to click the `edit` botton in the top right corner to add init script to your cluster.

[image]

Once you are in edit mode, you should be able to add init scripts to your cluster, like what is shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is expected and recently Databricks  has deprecated cluster-scoped init scripts on DBFS . The DBFS option in the UI exists to support legacy workloads and is not recommended. All init scripts stored in DBFS should be migrated to workspace file. All cluster scoped init scripts stored in DBFS should be migrated to workspace file.
Already Databricks suggesting to use migration script for existing dbfs init script migration [link](https://kb.databricks.com/cluster-named-init-script-migration-notebook?_gl=1*rn139f*_gcl_aw*R0NMLjE2ODg1NzYwMzIuQ2p3S0NBandxWlNsQmhCd0Vpd0Fmb1pVSUdtV25TQ1plME1GbEw1enlHS0pJdkJVSVRLaldndjhyMGJ5eVdPOVdDcUtDalNsYTVNcHZob0NIdlVRQXZEX0J3RQ..*_gcl_au*MjE4Njk4MDgwLjE2ODU0NjE5MDM.*_ga*MTk0MDY4NzQ1NS4xNjg0MjQ1NTI1*_ga_PQSEQ3RZQC*MTY4ODczODgzMC40NS4wLjE2ODg3Mzg4MzAuNjAuMC4w&_ga=2.16494320.714931442.1688525523-1940687455.1684245525).[image]

more info [link](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/where-to-move-cluster-init-scripts-after-latest-message-storing/td-p/8344)